# PHP - Structure for error handling

Tags: php, structure

I have a script which runs a bunch of jobs and validation and once everything passes it does an insert and returns json to an ajax script.

Now my script is something like this

```
$response = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){


    // some basic data


    // prevent duplicates
    if($check_duplicates){

        // create json error
        $helper->error_duplicate($name);
    }


    // some more data


    // run validation
    $validation = $helper->validate_form();

    // create json error if fails
    if($!$validation){
        $helper->error_validation();
    }

    // validate file
    $valid_file = $helper->validate_file();

    // create json error if fails
    if($!$valid_file){
        $helper->error_valid_file();
    }


    // more data


    //execute the insert 
    $insert_db = $database->execute_statement($insert_array,$file_name,$cleanup=true);

    // check if insert was successful
    if(!$insert_db){
        $response= array(
            "result" => "Failure",
            "title" => "Database Error",
            "message" => "There was an error with the insert"
        );
        echo (json_encode($response));
    }

    if($response == ""){
    $response= array(
        "result" => "Success",
        "title" => "Successful Insert",
        "message" => "The insert was successful"
    );
    echo (json_encode($response));
    }
}else{
    $response= array(
        "result" => "Failure",
        "title" => "No Access Allow",
        "message" => "This page is restricted"
    );
    echo (json_encode($response));
}
```

Now if one of the earlier validation fails then there is no need to continue on with the rest of the validation and insert but its going to be messy to have so many nested if's. Im sure this is a common situation but i am not sure the best way to handle it. Has anyone any suggestions or is there a better way to format this.

Comment: The concept is called abstraction. Breaking a large problem into smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$check_duplicates) $helper->error_duplicate($name);
elseif (!$validation = $helper->validate_form()) $helper->error_validation();
elseif (!$valid_file = $helper->validate_file()) $helper->error_valid_file();
elseif (!$insert_db = $database->execute_statement($insert_array,$file_name,$cleanup=true)) 
  echo json_encode(array(
    "result" => "Failure",
    "title" => "Database Error",
    "message" => "There was an error with the insert"
  ));
else 
  echo json_encode(array(
    "result" => "Success",
    "title" => "Successful Insert",
    "message" => "The insert was successful"
  ));
```